# Make a UIView stick to bottom of the ViewController frame in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgrect

I have created a UIView (it's just a blue rectangle) and I want it to stick to the bottom of the frame/view of the screen.

```
var nextBar = UIView()

nextBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 7/255, green: 152/255, blue: 253/255, alpha: 0.5)
nextBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 600, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)
self.view.addSubview(nextBar)
```

I'm assuming i need to add something in after the 'y:' part in the CGRect, but i can't seem to make it work or find anywhere that shows me this in swift.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

hmmm try this...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let theHeight = view.frame.size.height //grabs the height of your view

  var nextBar = UIView()

  nextBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 7/255, green: 152/255, blue: 253/255, alpha: 0.5)

  nextBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: theHeight - 50 , width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)

  self.view.addSubview(nextBar)

}
```

for the 'y:' in CRect, you're taking the size, in height, of the screen size and you're subtracting how many ever pixels you want. It will appear the same for what ever screen size.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why and what the * 0.95 is doing?

Comment: yeah. So when you create the 'let theHeight..' you are taking the Float of the screen size. Whether it's a 4s, 5s, 6, or 6+. So that number is maximum size of the screen. the '0.95' is a decimal or saying 95%. It's like saying, there a room thats 100ft long and someone tells you to point where 95% to the end of the room would be and u would roughly guess correctly, it doesnt matter if the room is 20ft, 50ft or 100ft long...it's just a percentage (%)...did it work?

Comment: Thanks for that. It did place the view at the bottom of the frame (i set it to 0.915), but it's different depending on what screen size it's on. So it appears fine on a 5s, but on a iPhone 6 its out of place again.

Comment: or:   '...y: theHeight - 20...' . your taking the screen size minus how many ever pixels u want. let me know if it works cause i need some points!! lol

Comment: that worked!! I set it to the height of what i made the View to be (in this case 50) so: theHeight - 50 , Thanks for the help, if you amend the answer you did above i shall accept it for you!

Comment: Ok, I just up dated my answer! :)

Comment: You're a lifesaver, 5 years later!

Answer (score 9):

You can do it programmatically using constraints

```
fileprivate func setupName(){
        let height = CGFloat(50)

        lblName.text = "Hello world"
        lblName.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        //Step 1
        lblName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        //Step 2
        self.view.addSubview(lblName)

        //Step 3
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            lblName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            lblName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            lblName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,constant: -height),
            lblName.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            ])

    }
```

Please refer [link](https://medium.com/@avinashraamireddy/view-that-sticks-to-bottom-of-screen-97eeb11a0247) for more details

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(50)]|", views: nextBar)
```